# How to make battery charging threshold effective after shutting down?

Tags: linux, power-management, laptop, thinkpad, battery

I can use below script to set/get battery charging threshold to stop battery charging at 85% using:

```
echo 85 > /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold
cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold
```

However, when my laptop is powered off, the setting isn't honored and the charging continues beyond the threshold. How to make this setting effective after shutting down?

For what is worth, my laptop is ThinkPad E15 and I have Arch Linux and Windows 11 installed. When I'm investigating this issue, I did the following:

- Boot to Windows, use Lenovo Vantage software to set the threshold, say `X%`.

  - Power off the laptop from Windows. The threshold `X%` is honored and battery is not charging beyond it.
  - Boot to Linux, the threshold is still `X%`. `cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_control_end_threshold` shows `X`.
  - The threshold is honored while Linux is running.
  - Power off the laptop from Linux. The threshold isn't honored and battery is charging beyond it.
  - Boot again to Windows, the threshold in Lenovo Vantage is still showing `X%`.
  - Power off the laptop again from Windows. The threshold is still honored and battery is not charging beyond it.
- Boot to Linux, write to `charge_control_end_threshold` to set the threshold, say `Y%`.

  - The threshold is honored while Linux is running.
  - Power off the laptop from Linux. The threshold isn't honored and battery is charging beyond it.
  - Boot to Windows, the threshold in Lenovo Vantage is still showing `X%` (not `Y%`).
- Boot to Windows, set the threshold, and force powering off the laptop by holding the power button for ~10 seconds.

  - The threshold isn't honored and battery is charging beyond it.
- Boot to Linux, set the threshold, and force powering off the laptop by holding the power button for ~10 seconds.

  - The threshold isn't honored and battery is charging beyond it.
- Boot to Windows, uninstall all the Lenovo Vantage software/driver I can find.

  - Power off the laptop from Windows. The threshold is still honored and battery is not charging beyond it.

I also notice that, when Windows powers off the laptop, the LED indicator on the power button blinks. It seems that, when Windows is powering off the laptop, it does something extra to persist the threshold and make it effect when the laptop is powered off. Any idea how to find out what it does and do the same thing when powering off from Linux?